# How to extend structure $A$ so said structure is isomorphic to $B$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, logic, first-order-logic

Let $A,B$ be structures of the same type such that we have an embedding $\phi:A\longrightarrow B$ (which is strong by definition). How can we prove there is a structure $C$ of the same type such that $A\subseteq C$ and there is a $g:C\longrightarrow B$ an isomoprhism?

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** We can define a structure isomorphic to $B$, on $C:=A\sqcup (B\setminus\phi(A))$ where $\sqcup$ denotes *disjoint union*.

Comment: Thank you, I can see that, however, I didn't know how to define $g:A\sqcup B \setminus \phi(A) \longrightarrow B$, should it be defined like, if $x\in A, g(x)=\phi(a)$ and otherwise $g(x)$ equals something else?

Comment: Yes. Otherwise $g$ keeps the element fixed.